# Multiple copies of a record based on formula

Tags: crystal-reports

Good afternoon,

I am very new to Crystal Reports, so am not sure where to look for this information and would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction or tell me if what I am asking for is impossible.

One of our departments uses a field called RecordChanges to note changes made to a record. The field is text and the department stores information there about the date a change is made and the type of change, separated by commas (i know this is terribly inefficient, but it's what I have to work with). I have  a Crystal Report that parses this text field and picks up the latest date and latest change made to the record. I would like to modify this report to include **ALL** the changes made to the record, so if the field RecordChanges of the data source has 3 dates, I would like this record to appear in my Crystal Report 3 times, once for each change that was made. How to parse the field I can figure out but where I'm stuck is how do I make the number of times a record appears equal to the number of dates found which is my {@DateFound} field?

Comment: Is it possible to estabish a maximum number of changes that your report will have to deal with?

Comment: Ordinarily if changes are made there is only 1 change that made to the record, but there are cases when 2 or 3 changes might happen so I am trying to have this report provide me with details of those additional changes. I would say realistically there wouldn't ever be more than 5 changes to an order.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lack of details, but as far as I understood the problem and assuming that you did state in the comment that "there wouldn't ever be more than 5 changes to an order", here is a first try to tackle the situation.

I will assume that you already have a formula that "parses this text field and picks up the latest date and latest change made to the record". And that you know how to adjust this formula to pick up each of the record changes. I will name this formula as {@Parser1}.

1. Based on {@Parser1}, create other 4 formulas: {@Parser2}, {@Parser3}, {@Parser4}, {@Parser5}. As you probably presume, each formula must be changed to parser the Nth occurrence of the record change.
2. Create 5 details sections.
3. Put each formula in each detail section.
4. Suppress the detail section wich formula is null or empty.

That's it.

The limitation is that you can have at most 5 record changes.

This is an awkward solution, but it is necessary (as far as I know) since Crystal Reports works based on your data rows. It iterates over the rows, but cannot "generate" more rows by itself. If you can manipulate the data source, you can create other solutions.

You still need to do the magic trick to pickup the Nth change from the text.